# How to remove "ghost audiobooks" from Finder to iPhone synchronization list

Tags: itunes, finder, data-synchronization, bug, audiobook

Every time I sync my audiobooks via Finder with my iPhone I get a warning about some files missing. It's caused by 2 audiobooks which doesn't even exist anymore (probably had them in the past but not anymore). In Books app there're no such records except the last one. What should I do to remove them from sync list? Apple support spent 1 hour on this and told me nothing can be done :) There's no iTunes anymore and they were added by iTunes I believe. Their records need to be hidden somewhere in old iTunes related data.

[image]